# How to make one object inherit from another without using __proto__?

Tags: javascript

I use the code below in Firefox to set the prototype inheritance relationship between two objects:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};

b.__proto__ = a;
a.dosomething = function() {
   alert('ok');
};
b.dosomething();  //ok
```

but it only works on Firefox due to `__proto__` being only available in Firefox.

In other web browsers, if `a` and `b` were created using some constructor function, I could use

```
b.constructor.prototype = a;
```

to set the inheritance relationship.

But in the case above, the constructors of `a` and `b` are both `Object`.
I can not change the prototype of `Object`.

Is there any way to set the inheritance relationship except by using `__proto__`?

Comment: Did you mean `__proto__`?

Comment: yes, it is __proto__

Comment: In the above code aren't you setting b as a prototype of a? 
In the below code why are you doing `b.constructor.prototype = a` instead of `b.prototype=a`? 
Also you are right object is the mother prototype in js, i ask just to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It creates an object whose prototype is the object passed to it.

```js
var a = {};
var b = Object.create(a);

a.dosomething = function() {
   alert ('ok');
};
b.dosomething(); // ok
```

You can also use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) for objects that already exist. You really, really should *not* do this if you can avoid it. It leads to serious performance issues.

```js
var a = {};
var b = {};

Object.setPrototypeOf(b, a);

a.dosomething = function() {
   alert ('ok');
};
b.dosomething(); // ok
```

Comment: that is only for creating new b(new object), can I set the inherit relationship if a and b have existed?

Comment: @arachide Yup. See my edit.

Comment: great! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

**Do not alter the prototype of an existing object**.

> **Warning:** Changing the `[[Prototype]]` of an object is, by the nature
>   of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very
>   slow operation, in ***every*** browser and JavaScript engine. The
>   effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and
>   far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in
>   `obj.__proto__ = ...` statement, but may extend to ***any*** code that
>   has access to ***any*** object whose `[[Prototype]]` has been altered.
>   If you care about performance you should avoid setting the
>   `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a new object with the
>   desired `[[Prototype]]` using [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

And if you do so, the standard way is [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), not [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

The proper way is

```js
var a = {};
var b = Object.create(a);
a.dosomething = function(){
  console.log('ok');
};
b.dosomething();
```

Your `b.constructor.prototype = a;` approach is useless. If `b` is an instance of a constructor `C`, that code will only affect instances constructed after the change, but not `b`.